# Junit test case failure:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: junit, noclassdeffounderror

While building the project from the source (svn repository) code, (including junit test cases) junit passes without any error. However while running junit individually, the junit fails. I have added all necessary jar files. java, jdk path and environment variables are all correct.

Below is the exception that I get, please help:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError because the org.springframework.beans.jar (which contains org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor) is missing from your classpath when you are running the test.

You must be running the individual test in a different way than when you are running all the tests.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I added this jar "spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE". which has "org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor" but when I run the test case now I am getting the below ERROR [main] (TestContextManager.java:258) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a4181c],java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext,

Comment: Caused by:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated:

Comment: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found..................... The methods of execution is: During complete build, which is automated using 'build.xml' file, test cases pass. but when I right click on individual or group of testcases and do 'run as-->junit', it fails. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: When running using build.xml you are using the classpath of how you are running ant. When clicking on 'run as->junit' you are using the classpath for your Eclipse project. You can configure this via Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries.

Comment: Hi Paul, I had missed jaxb-impl.jar, once I added it, its working fine. Thank you for the help. :-)

Comment: and I removed the "spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE" jar.